# unix sed not backtracking to finish the job

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to make a script to convert postgres CSV dumps into Oracle csv dumps. Aka, I'm trying to replace "true" with "Y" and "false" with "N".

So I want a script called to_oracle like this:

```
echo "false,false,false,true" | to_oracle
N,N,N,Y
```

So here is my attempt:

```
sed -E -e 's:(,|^)true(,|$):\1Y\2:g' -e 's:(,|^)false(,|$):\1N\2:g' "$@"
```

The logic is that a field in a CSV file either starts with beginning of line or a comma "," and it ends with either the end of line or a comma ","

The problem with this script is that it greedily absorbs the comma and thus every second field doesn't work:

```
echo "false,false,false,true" | to_oracle
N,false,N,Y
```

Now I suppose I could pipe it to the script twice, and that would do the job, but I'm wondering is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: `sed -E ':a;s/(,|^)false(,|$)/\1N\2/;ta; :b;s/(,|^)true(,|$)/\1Y\2/;tb'`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/qDVNZb)

Comment: Did any answer work for you?

Comment: Yes thanks Wiktor, I used your response, although I'm sure the others are ok too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed, you may use

```
sed -E ':a;s/(,|^)false(,|$)/\1N\2/;ta; :b;s/(,|^)true(,|$)/\1Y\2/;tb'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/qDVNZb)

**Details**

- `-E` will enable POSIX ERE syntax
- `':a;s/(,|^)false(,|$)/\1N\2/;ta;` will recursively replace `false` in between commas or start/end of string with `N`
- `:b;s/(,|^)true(,|$)/\1Y\2/;tb'` will recursively replace `true` in between commas or start/end of string with `Y`.

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` version:

```
echo "false,false,false,true" | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i=="true"?"Y":"N"}1'
N,N,N,Y
```

It test one by one field, if its `true` use `Y`, else use `N`

If you like to test for `false` as well

```
echo "false,false,false,true" | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=($i=="true"?"Y":($i=="false"?"N":"other"))}1'
N,N,N,Y
```